# JQuery error while enqueue script? (Wordpress, JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have enqueue scripts of js like skroller.js, swiper.js etc and facing some errors i don't know how to fix

this is my how i enqueue

```
wp_register_script('modernizr', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');

wp_register_script('jquery-3.4.1', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-3.4.1');


wp_register_script( 'jQuery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js' );
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');

wp_register_script('skrollr', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('skrollr');

wp_register_script('swiper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/swiper.js');
wp_enqueue_script('swiper');

wp_register_script('themejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/actions.js');
wp_enqueue_script('themejs');
```

[image]

Comment: The error is in your `actions.js` file. Click the line number on the right of the console error and it will show you the relevant line of code.

Comment: seems the library issue you are trying to include. (named skrillr.min.js)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please tell me what is the problem in my code by reading the error in the image?

Comment: @syedashar321 Parameter 1 for `getComputedStyle` Should be `Element` type. [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Remove the slim js and try